# R: Beginner Question: Recursive Function On Function

Tags: r

I have a question. My main problem with reading solutions online is that I cannot understand 95% of them because the answers are usually too technical.

Question: I have created a basic function that returns one answer. Now I need to make this same function repeats itself for N/2 times and returns N/2 answers.

The base function is as per below. User inputs the function with a variable N. Assuming he inputs N=100, the function generates list a, list b and list c. Then the function counts how many times a criteria is achieved and returns the count value. In the base case, list b is created with the first 10 elements of list a and list c is created with the remaining N-10 elements.

```
f <- function (N) {
  count <- 0
  for (nn in 1:100) {
    a <- sample(1:N)
    b <- a [1:10] 
    c <- a [11:N]
    pass <- which(c>=max(b))
    if (length(pass) == 1) {
        count <- count + 1
    }
  }
  return (count)
}

answer <- f(100)
answer
```

The recursive function has to make this base function repeats N/2 times. The splitting of list b and c is no longer based on 10 elements and (N-10) elements. It is now based on 1) 1, N-1 elements, then 2) 2, N-2 elements, then 3) 3, N-3 elements and so on until the N/2 case (which is both lists are split evenly).

As such I tried this but it does not work. I need a recursive function that can generate N/2 answers which is one answer for each of the cases. As I am really new to Programming, I hope the suggestions can be explicit. I may not have the ability to understand implicit and partial codes.

Thank you everyone for being so kind and taking the time to help others.

```
f <- function (N) {
  for (mm in 1: N/2) {
    number <- list()
    count <- 0
    for (nn in 1:100) {
      a <- sample(1:N)
      b <- a [1:mm] 
      c <- a [mm+1:N]
      pass <- which(c>=max(b))
      if (length(pass) >= 1) {
        count <- count + 1
      }
    }
    number[mm] <- count
  }
}

answer <- f(100)
answer
# NULL
```

The latest edited code that a helpful commenter (Oliver) has come up with is as per below. But it is only working for one case. Basically the function attempts to slice a list of 100 random numbers into 2 parts, b and c. Then it attempts to see if c contains exactly one number that is higher than the highest number in b. The for-loop (mm in 1:(N/2)) simulates a continuous slicing action for b and c. It starts with 1 and ends with 50 (N/2). When it is 1, b has 1 element and c has 100-1 elements, when it is 2, b has 2 elements and c has 98 elements... with the last case being b and c both having 50 elements.

```
f <- function (N) {
  for (mm in 1: (N/2)) {
    number <- list()
    count <- 0
    for (nn in 1:100) {
      a <- sample(1:N)
      b <- a [1:mm] 
      c <- a [mm+1:N]
      pass <- which(c>=max(b))
      if (length(pass) == 1) {
        count <- count + 1
      }
    }
    number[mm] <- count
  }
  number
}

bb <- f(100)
bb

[[46]]
NULL

[[47]]
NULL

[[48]]
NULL

[[49]]
NULL

[[50]]
[1] 26
```

If the code works correctly, the expected answers for [46], [47], [48] and [49] should be 20+ and not NULL. I believe the code for `number[mm] <- count` is not working as intended. I believe `number[mm]` is not being successfully transmitted to the final code `number` except for `number[50]` which is transmitted correctly.

Comment: Recursion means that you are calling your function (`f`) within itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO, thank you for a well formulated question.

First things straight. Recursion refers to the calling of a function within the same function as in the (not very explicit) example below:

```
f <- function(x){
    some code
    n <- f(x2)
    some more code
    return(x3)
}
```

Now for your problem. You're close to the answer you want. Three things got messed up in the process,

1. Remember your parenthesis.
2. Returning the output
3. Resetting the `number` at each iteration.

For 1. `R` reads code left to right, and will be very strict in how it calculates your code. `1:N/2` is equivalent to `1: N/2` which is equivalent to `c(1, 2, ..., N) / 2`. You're looking for `1:(N/2)` or `seq(1, N/2)`, and you likely would like to use either `floor` or `ceiling` for rounding uneven results of `N/2`, such as `5/2=2.5`, `13/2=6.5` etc.

For 2. you are currently not returning anything from your function. In `R` you can explicitly return a value using `return(...)`, or you can simply type out the object/number as the last thing in your function.

For 3, note that in the outer loop, you are calling `number <- list()`. At each iteration of the outer loop, this will reset the list of counts, thus removing any previous answer. This should be moved

Putting these together, getting the piece of code right amounts to the example below:

```
f <- function (N) {
  number <- list() # <=== initiate your canister only once.
  for (mm in 1:(N/2)) { #<=== remember parenthesis. Or use seq(1, N/2)
    count <- 0
    for (nn in 1:100) {
      a <- sample(1:N)
      b <- a [1:mm] 
      c <- a [mm+1:N]
      pass <- which(c>=max(b))
      if (length(pass) >= 1) {
        count <- count + 1
      }
    }
    number[mm] <- count
  }
  number #<== or return(number)
}
```

I wouldn't mind giving a few general suggestions, but it isn't quite clear to me, what the greater picture of the function is.

Comment: Thank you for the great help. Unfortunately, the code suggested only works for the final case when mm = N/2 = 50. The result of the code is NULL for cases 1 to 49 which means they are not working. The expected answer should be something like number[50] = 20+, number [49] = 20+, number [48] = 20+.... But what I got was number[50] = 20+, number [49] = NULL, number [48] = NULL

Comment: Basically the function attempts to slice a list of 100 random numbers into 2 parts, b and c. Then it attempts to see if c contains exactly one number that is higher than the highest number in b. the mm is a continuous slicing function of b and c. It starts with 1 and ends with 50 (N/2). When it is 1, b has 1 element and c has 100-1 elements, when it is 2, b has 2 elements and c has 98 elements etc.

Comment: I've noticed a slight oversight on my part. You are resetting `number` on every iteration of the out loop with `number <- list()` basically removing any previous calculation. This should be moved outside the loop entirely. In a moment the answer will be updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that your first function works as intended, it seems reasonable to build on that to create the second function. If we modify it my making the split point variable and assignable as an argument, we can easily make a second function that simply loops over split points.

```
f <- function(N, d) {
  count <- 0
  for (nn in 1:100) {
    a <- sample(1:N)
    b <- a[1:d]
    c <- a[(d+1):N]
    pass <- sum(c >= max(b))
    if (pass == 1) {
        count <- count + 1
    }
  }
  count
}

set.seed(1)
f(50, 10)
# [1] 16


f2 <- function(N) {
    l <- floor(N/2)
    v <- vector(length=l)
    for (i in 1:l) {
        v[i] <- f(N, i)
    }
    v
}

set.seed(1)
f2(10)
# [1]  9 13 26 30 27
```

As noted by others, this isn't a recursive function, but an iterative one. It iterates over the integers `1:floor(1/N)`.

---

If you want to learn about recursive functions I'd suggest you start with something simpler, f.ex. one of the go-tos, a fibonacci sequence generator. Here you can see that `fib()` is called inside `fib()` itself, and each time it's called, `x` is extended with the sum of the last two elements, and `n` is reduced with one. This continues until `n` is zero, at which point `x` is returned.

```
fib <- function(x, n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        x <- c(x, sum(tail(x, 2)))
        fib(x, n-1)
    } else {
        x
    }
}

fib(c(1, 1), 10)
#  [1]   1   1   2   3   5   8  13  21  34  55  89 144
```